# Workflow error: The value 'Value' cannot be read as type 'Int32'

Tags: workflow, error, lookup-column, workflow-lookup

I've a list named `APE - Opções` with this values:

```
Título            | Nota
Nunca             | 1
Algumas vezes     | 2
Frequente         | 3
Sempre            | 4
N/A               | 0
```

[image: Colunm Nota from APE - Opções]

And a list called `Avaliação de Experiência` where I use the list `APO - Opções` on colunm `Comunicação` of type Lookup.

[image: Colunm Comunicação from list Avaliação de Experiência]

In my workflow under list `Avaliação de Experiência` I've var `Nota` of type `number` it should receive the colunm `Nota` from `APE - Opções` through field `Comunicação`:

[image: Workflow]

But I've this error:

> RequestorId: aa076974-78c8-8b23-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. 
>   Exception details: System.InvalidCastException: **The value 'Value' cannot be read as type 'Int32'**. at Microsoft.Activities.
>   GetDynamicValueProperty`1.CheckedRead(String propertyName, DynamicItem value) at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`
>   1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`
>   1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation) 
>   Exception from activity GetDynamicValueProperty ToString DynamicActivity DynamicActivity Assign Calculando Nota Sequence Flowchart Cooperador Avaliado.WorkflowXaml_00e5de9f_8324_4850_92ac_7a2ef8350c40

<sub><sub>Sorry, my English is not very good.</sub></sub>

Comment: did you try as a double?

Comment: Hi @Marco I found solution, in one minute I'll post the answer... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the relationship on search:

I change this:

[image: Wrong search]

For this:

[image: Correct search]

Before was searching for the value, I changed to search the ID and it worked.